# Index Out of range error when converting my Jupyter Notebook into Kubeflow pipline with Kale

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I am running a simple ANN model on a Jupyter Notebook Server in Kubeflow. I ran my code in my notebook to see if it worked, and everything ran just fine with expected outputs.

However, when I use Kale to convert the notebook into a Kubeflow pipeline, I'm getting the following error: [error message in load_data logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jX9M.png) during my load_data step. Here is my code block that works in the notebook: [working codeblock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s4Y0.png)

Does anyone know what the error could be? If anyone would like steps to recreate the environment, please let me know.

Here is my code for reference:
https://github.com/sumanthnallamotu/kale/blob/master/artificial_neural_network.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. In your function definitions, if you're dealing with indexes, make sure to pass them as parameters. For example:

**def example(x):
return x[2]**

should actually be:

**def example(x, index):
return x[index]**

Otherwise, you will get a list index out of range error when converting the notebook into a KF pipeline through Kale because Kale will read it as if you are accessing the arbitrary x in your function definition.